# Replace Seagate 500Gb with WD 1 TB

Tags: hard-drive

I had a harddisk failure, luckily no work is lost.

My present hard disk is Seagate Momentus 5400.6. It is 500Gb with the following specifications

[image]

Now I wish to replace the internal hdd with Western Digital WD10JPVX with the following  specification

[image]

I have learned that this can be done as long as the height, widht & depth matches. According to specification their is difference in depth. Seagate has a depth of 100.5mm whereas WD has a depth of 100.2mm.

*Will difference in depth be factor or the difference is negligible?*

Also the harddisk is screwed on a casing as shown in the image below

[image]

*Will WD harddisk fit into the casing and screws?*

Comment: You're worrying about an insignificant difference.  Yes, it will fit.

Comment: Even if 0.3 mm made a difference, notice that the replacement is the smaller one.

Comment: Go for it! You'll be fine :)

Comment: If you 500GB disk was a 3.5" drive, a 1TB 3.5" drive will fit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The distance of the side and bottom screws for 2.5 inch hard drives are entirely standard from the bottom of the drive. More importantly, mounted in the correct location, the sata connector for a *thinner* drive will always line up with the connector in a system designed for a thicker Z height drive. 10mm is the 'old' standard but 7mm and 5mm drives exist.

Considering these are 10mm drives, and your thickness difference is *negligible* the new drive absolutely would fit and work, as would a 7mm or 5mm drive